# Set a custom cursor image with React styled components

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to set a custom cursor image when hovered on a specific element. I've tried putting my `svg` icon in `src` folder and call it in styled components as

```
const HStyles = styled.h3`
   cursor: url("images/pen-tool.svg");
 `;
```

But it doesn't change the cursor to pen image. I've also tried

```
 cursor: url('images/pen-tool.svg'),
  url('images/pen-tool.cur');

cursor: url('images/pen-tool.svg'),
  move;
```

My svg has a width and height defined in it's `svg` tag but still no work. Am I missing something here ?
You can check my code sandbox sample [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-cookies-yp609?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Does it work in a normal (non-React, no-JS) HTML+CSS file?

Comment: I just tested it and it doesn't seem to work with plain HTML and CSS as well

Answer (score 0):

```
const HStyles = styled.h3`
   cursor: url("images/pen-tool.svg");
 `;
```

Styled components is CSS-in-JS. Your can't write declarations like "images/pen-tool.svg" and have to call variable from import.

Just import images/pen-tool.svg and call it like:

```
import penTool from "./images/pen-tool.svg";

const HStyles = styled.h3`
  cursor: url(${HStyles}), auto;
`;
```

and don't forget "auto"

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this also doesn't work. I've updated my codesandbox with your answer.

Comment: codesandbox can't change cursor (by privacy or security reason, I don't remember exactly). Just try your code (from codesandbox) in react. I checked this code in my webstorm environment and it work fine.

Comment: For understanding. Codesandbox has exception in this problem. But if you want change cursor by styled components - you did right in your updated codesandbox example